# Compile error for cordova google maps sdk

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, google-maps-sdk-ios, ionic2, phonegap-cli

This is my first mobile app. I am targeting any the latest versions of Android and iOS. I am developing with Cordova CLI (using ionic).

I'm getting following error when compiling with cordova google-maps-sdk plugin

```
/Users/basit/projects/app-mobile/platforms/ios/app/Plugins/plugin.google.maps/GroundOverlay.m:100:47: error: property 'request' not found on object of type 'UIView *'
        NSString *currentPath = [self.webView.request.URL absoluteString];



GoogleMaps.h:11:
In file included from /Users/basit/projects/app-mobile/platforms/ios/app/Plugins/plugin.google.maps/GoogleMapsViewController.h:12:
/Users/basit/projects/app-mobile/platforms/ios/app/Plugins/plugin.google.maps/PluginUtil.h:66:58: note: passing argument to parameter 'theWebView' here
+ (NSString *)getAbsolutePathFromCDVFilePath:(UIWebView*)theWebView cdvFilePath:(NSString *)cdvFilePath;
                                                         ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        CompileC build/app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/app.build/Objects-normal/i386/GroundOverlay.o app/Plugins/plugin.google.maps/GroundOverlay.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

Comment: Please **answer the following questions in your post**.
Is this your first hybrid App? Are you using the Desktop App?
What is your target platform and their target versions: Android 4,5,6? iOS 7,8,9?
Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link.
Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Comment: Is this your FIRST HYBRID app?

Comment: Are you still having this issue? Why did you give an Answer?

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 because that solved the problem.

Comment: Okay. Happy to see you are working. FWIW: there are two similar tags `phonegap-cli` is yours, not `phonegap-build`. Best of Luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the warning says, "This plugin is not compatible with Cordova-iOS 4.*.*"

I downgraded from 4.* to 3.9.0 and now it compiles just fine!

```
ionic platform remove ios
ionic platform add ios@3.9.0
```

Comment: Could you check on iOS (in Xcode) if your app memory is growing ? Because I am getting some memory leaks which I think are related to google maps cordova.

Comment: @DenkoMancheski I'm not sure how to check for memory leaks.. I'm very new to ios app or even any app, but it works fine for me now on IOS. android is another story (cant even get it up and running on it)